# Optimize message broadcast in golang chat application

Tags: go, chat, channel, goroutine

I'm writing a chat application with Golang. I have below sample code below that needs to be optimized.

```
type Hub struct {
  Clients         map[int64]*Client
  Broadcast       chan *model.ChannelMessage 
  SingleBroadcast chan *model.ChannelMessage //buffered with len 10
}

func (h *Hub) SingleChatRun() {
  //handle message transfer between users
  for {
    m := <-h.SingleBroadcast
    saveMessageToDB()
    writeMessageToClientWebsocket()
    writeMessageToSenderWebsocket()  
  }
}

func (c *Client) ReadMessage(){
  //read message from client websocket
  for {
    clientMessage := c.Conn.ReadJSON(&clientMessage)
    //one to one message 
    hub.SingleBroadcast <- clientMessage
  }
}
```

The problem is, "SingleBroadcast" channel is blocking and slow in each message transfer which is bad.

1. remove the usage of "SingleBroadcast" and handle the "3 functions" inside the "ReadMessage"
   1.1. this option makes the reading from websocket slow, but only for very active users. also use more resources
   1.2. making it faster by using goroutine for each message to handle the "3 functions". this is faster but so many goroutine
2. use goroutine to handle "SingleBroadcast" like below:

```
func (h *Hub) SingleChatRun() {
  //handle message transfer between users
  for {
    m := <-h.SingleBroadcast
    go func(){
       saveMessageToDB()
       writeMessageToClientWebsocket()
       writeMessageToSenderWebsocket()
    }
  }
}
```

2.1. this is slower than method 1, but less goroutine creation

3. using message queue/broker
4. using pool of goroutines. idk

I'm new to Golang and these things are confusing.

Comment: Regarding option 1: It is desirable to limit the rate that the application reads from the connection to rate that the application can process that data.  Without that limit, there's no bound the resources used by the application.

Comment: @cerise-limón tnx, you kinda right

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to suggest a holistic solution without an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but here's what comes to mind.

So, while channels are very useful when you need them, they're often overused when learning the language. This can be accomplished without using any — though I'd recommend buffering writes to the database with one. Since the database is usually a bottleneck, you don't want writes there to grow linearly.

```golang
const (
  avgClients    = 1024
  dbBufSize     = 64
  flushInterval = time.Second * 5
)

type Hub struct {
  clients         map[int64]*Client
  rows            chan *model.Row  // Or whatever your type is
}

func NewHub() *Hub {
  rows := make(chan *model.Row, dbBufSize)
  go flusher(rows, dbBufSize, flushInterval)

  // You'll need a method to to handle registering clients
  // to the map, potentially with a mutex if each instance
  // of 'h.Send()' needs access to the map.
  return &Hub{
    clients: make(map[int64]*Client, avgClients),
    rows: rows,
  }
}

func (h *Hub) Send(src *Client, msg *model.ChannelMessage) {
  h.rows <- makeRow(msg)
  // Logic
}


type Client {
  hub  *Hub
  conn *websocket.Conn // Or whatever the type is
}

func (c *Client) Loop(){
  var msg *model.ChannelMessage
  for {
    msg = c.conn.ReadJSON(&msg)

    // Run this with 'go c.hub.Send(c, msg) if you need
    // to process messages before previous ones are finished
    c.hub.Send(c, msg)
  }
}


// flusher accepts rows and writes to the database when the buffer
// exceeds 'size' or 'interval' has passed without a flush
func flusher(rows <-chan *model.Row, size int, interval time.Duration) {
  buf := make([]*model.Row, 0, size)
  ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)

  flush := func() {
    writeDB(buf)
    buf = buf[:0]
  }

  for {
    select {
    case row := <-rows:
      buf = append(buf, row)
      if len(buf) >= size {
        flush()
        ticker.Reset(interval)
      }
    case <-ticker.C:
      if len(buf) > 0 {
        flush()
      }
    }
  }
}
```